# TDAmeritrade API get user positions

Tags: python, json

I am building software to track my portfolio and trade from. I am currently trying to get my account positions from the TD API.

```
acct_endpt = 'https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/accounts/{accountId}'
full_url_acct = acct_endpt.format(accountId='accountId')

account = requests.get(url=full_url_acct,
                       params={'fields' : 'positions', 'apikey' : 'apikey'})

acct_content = json.loads(account.content)
```

My code above is returning me the following error:

`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 11 (char 11)`

**Update:**
I removed the line containing `json.loads()` as it was returning a 401 error *[An error message indicating the caller must pass a valid AuthToken in the HTTP authorization request header]*. I must be passing the `fields` and `apikey` parameters incorrectly. How would the syntax look to properly pass these parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters look correct, but I think the url formatting isn't doing what you want. Instead, you can format your url using f-string as follows:

```
accountId = "ACCOUNT_ID"
acct_endpt = f"https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/accounts/{accountId}"
```

Comment: Used f-string, however, it is still returning a 401 error. Which means it's not receiving my api/authorization key. How can I fix this?

Comment: @BrianCos Looking at the TD Ameritrade API documentation, looks like this uses a bearer token. Prior to this call, are you getting the bearer token via the Post Access Token API?


Sources:
Accounts:
https://developer.tdameritrade.com/account-access/apis/get/accounts/%7BaccountId%7D-0

Bearer Token:
https://developer.tdameritrade.com/authentication/apis/post/token-0